# Cannot link C++ using tensorflow C++ API tensorflow_cc.lib on Windows 10/Visual C++ 2017 -- undefined symbol r2.0

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow

I have a C++ program that I am trying to use with the tensorflow C++ API. I have it working fine on linux. But I cannot get the dumb thing to link on Windows. I am using the r2.0 branch of tensorflow. I am building tensorflow from source using Visual C++ 2017 (v14.16.27023). It took a while but I finally got bazel to build tensorflow_cc.dll and tensorflow_cc.lib. Linking my program to the tensorflow_cc.lib gave 3 undefined tensorflow symbols initially

```
?_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_@tensorflow@@3VTensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal@1@A
??0SessionOptions@tensorflow@@QEAA@XZ
?LoadSavedModel@tensorflow@@YA?AVStatus@1@AEBUSessionOptions@1@AEBVRunOptions@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@6@QEAUSavedModelBundle@1@@Z
```

I read some github bug reports and discovered that there is a complex method used to export a subset of the global symbols into the .lib file that involves a python program tensorflow/tools/def_file_filter/def_file_filter.py.tpl and someone showed how to put extra symbols in that to add to the set exported. I went ahead and did that:

```
diff --git a/tensorflow/tools/def_file_filter/def_file_filter.py.tpl ...
@@ -154,6 +154,9 @@ def main():
       else:
         def_fp.write("\t" + decorated + " DATA\n")
       taken.add(decorated)
+    def_fp.write("\t??0SessionOptions@tensorflow@@QEAA@XZ\n")
+    def_fp.write("\t?_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_@tensorflow@@3VTensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal@1@A DATA\n")
+    def_fp.write("\t?LoadSavedModel@tensorflow@@YA?AVStatus@1@AEBUSessionOptions@1@AEBVRunOptions@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@6@QEAUSavedModelBundle@1@@Z\n")
     def_fp.close()

   exit_code = proc.wait()
```

I then re-bazeled tensorflow_cc.lib and it fixed TWO of the THREE. I then discovered that the one that remained undefined upon link was actually already exported:

```
?_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_@tensorflow@@3VTensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal@1@A
```

So I actually removed it from my changes to def_file_filter.py.tpl. That particular symbol is defined in a file generated from a .proto file into bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.pb.cc. It is a global scope class instance:

```
static void InitDefaultsscc_info_TensorShapeProto_tensorflow_2fcore_2fframework_2ftensor_5fshape_2eproto() {
  GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

  {
    void* ptr = &::tensorflow::_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_;
    new (ptr) ::tensorflow::TensorShapeProto();
    ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::OnShutdownDestroyMessage(ptr);
  }
  ::tensorflow::TensorShapeProto::InitAsDefaultInstance();
}
```

I looked at the symbols in tensorflow_cc.lib and did find an entry related to this symbol:

```
tensorflow_cc.dll:
0000000000000000 I .idata$4
0000000000000000 I .idata$5
0000000000000000 I .idata$6
                 U __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_tensorflow_cc
0000000000000000 I __imp_?_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_@tensorflow@@3VTensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal@1@A
```

I am not sure if it correct or not. Presumably not since I am still getting:

```
link tfseg.dll .wsl.obj/plugin.obj .wsl.obj/segTask.obj .wsl.obj/tfseg....
   Creating library C:/root/ispace/plugins/tfseg/bin_release/tfseg.lib and object C:/root/ispace/plugins/tfseg/bin_release/tfseg.exp
tfseg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class tensorflow::TensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal tensorflow::_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_" (?_TensorShapeProto_default_instance_@tensorflow@@3VTensorShapeProtoDefaultTypeInternal@1@A)
C:/root/ispace/plugins/tfseg/bin_release/tfseg.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am at my wits end and very frustrated. Anyone seen this before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this link error. It is ugly and I still feel that something is very wrong with the tensorflow build on windows. But in case someone else runs into the same problem, this is what I did. I added the .o file that contains the missing symbol (tensor_shape.pb.o) directly to my link line, and that produced a whole bunch more unresolved symbols, all from google protobuf. I then hunted around and found some protobuf ".a" files and added them in. Miraculously, it worked. Here is a summary of the new link line:

```
cl.exe -MD ... plugin.obj .wsl.obj/segTask.obj .wsl.obj/tfseg.obj /link /dll ... c:/root/tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/_objs/protos_all_proto_cc_impl/tensor_shape.pb.o c:/root/tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/libprotobuf.a c:/root/tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/libprotobuf_lite.a c:/root/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorflow_cc.lib
```

I was able to successfully use tensorflow at the point and just needed tensorflow_cc.dll to be in my LoadLibrary search path.